# Run a Windows executable in XP compatibility mode from the command line?

Tags: windows, compatibility, command-line

Is there a way I can set the compatibility mode of an .exe file through the command line on execution of said file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Application Compatibility Toolkit (ACT) to do this,
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=24da89e9-b581-47b0-b45e-492dd6da2971&displaylang=en.

First you pick the compatibility settings for the application and it will save to an SDB file.

Then to install the SDB you use the following command.

```
sdbinst -q <path to sdb file>
```

Then whenever you run the EXE you want after that point Windows will apply the compatibility settings.